# Unable to understand reason for segmenation fault while accessing a char string

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, strcpy

segmentation fault after running the following code:

```
int main(){
    const char *string = "This is not reverse";
    char *reverse;
    char temp;
    int length, i = 0;
    length = strlen(string);
    strcpy(reverse, string);

    while(i < (length/2)){
       temp = *(reverse+i); // this is the reason for segmentation fault..but why? 
       i++;
    }

}
```

could someone please explain the reason for the same

Comment: You tell `strcpy` to copy `string` to `reverse` but never actually provide a value for `reverse`.

Comment: `reverse` doen't point to anything.

Comment: got it, sorry for this question..it was my mistake..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to allocate space for *reverse*. For example

```
char *reverse = malloc(strlen(string) + 1);
```

By the way, the rest of the code seems to have an algorithmic bug.  I think what you wanted to do was something like:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <malloc.h>

int main(){
  const char *string = "This is not reverse";
  int length = strlen(string);
  char *reverse = malloc(length + 1);

  int i = 0;
  while(i < length){
    *(reverse + i) = *(string + length - i - 1);
    i++;
  }

  printf("%s\n", reverse);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: you are right, how could I miss that..reverse = malloc((strlen(string)+1)*sizeof(char));

Comment: Yep, and you are right this is not C++, so _malloc_ not _new_.  You don't really need the `sizeof(char)` because that is always `1`.

Comment: Also, if you were using the latest C compilers, you could do: `char reverse[strlen(string)+1];`

Comment: Thanks..for answering this question so patiently..and yes I was practicing some string algorithms but got stuck here itself..yes above code is incomplete :)

Answer (score -1):

instead of  `strcpy(reverse, string);` use `reverse = string`, Because you don't need to allocate space for reverse, Just point reverse to string i.e `reverse = string`

Comment: if I point it to the address of a const char i won't be able to edit it. does that makes sense?

Comment: @user2901020: you're right that you must copy the string literal to an array that can be modified.

Comment: user2901020: Has valid point, in that case either you define `const` pointer, Because looking at your code it seems you are not modifying string. Or you have to copy string. If you think it's i am happy to delete my answer, as it might be misleading

Comment: hmm..but, why would you like to delete your answer..many people might think like that..even my question is not an awesome question..it is all about learning either from right or wrong things..in fact, we learn more from the wrong things..cheers!